# PHP die suddenly stops to show string

Tags: php, die

I am a noob with php. I have been using for more than 1 year a script in php to comunicate with an arduino.

Arduino sends data to my php script and it answers with text that arduino can read to know if the data has been correctly saved or not. Also there is a way to get some settings that arduino needs when it starts from my mysql database.

The way that I have been returing an answer to my arduino is with "DIE" function.

I have this php files (pseudo code):

**function.php** (several functions)

```
function response($str) {
    die('<' . $str . '>');  //< and > is to let arduino knows exactly the answer
}   

function get_settings() {
    $response = "";
    // ...... so response is completed
    return $response;
}
```

**index.php** (this file includes a "require_once" for both `function.php` and `gate.php`, among other functions. It is the main file)

**gate.php** (script file that recieves data from arduino and need to send an answer)

```
//it gets data from $_GET and saves it into a mysql database
//After that:
if ($result) {                      
    response('OK');                     
} else {
    response('BAD_VALUES');
}
//And with other params in the $_GET, it does:
if ($_GET['k'] === ARDUINO_KEY) {
    response(get_settings());
} else {
    response('BAD KEY');
}
```

The problem since this week is:
1. If I want to get "response('OK');" from `gate.php` I DON'T get anything, also in Chrome I can't see anything
2. If I want to get "response(get_settings());" from gate.php I DO get the information and Chrome is showing it.
3. If i change this line "response(get_settings());", to "response('OK');" or to "response("OK");" I DON'T get anything, also in Chrome I can't see anything

What do you think about this? Why a function that return a string works, and a string not. Why has it been working for months and suddenly not?

I have checked it in my "freehosting plan" and with usbWebserver.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What changed? Have you checked the error logs? And can you better explain what you mean with: "Why a function that return a string works, and a string not." ?

Comment: Something's preventing response() from working correctly. You need to check your error logs to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: "Why a function that return a string works, and a string not." Sorry for my english. I mean that it works perfectly with a function that returns a string, but it doesn't work if I write directly an string.

Comment: Thank @MichaelGregoire. I don't know exactly how to check error logs, but the stranger thing is that it works until this week. It is very strange for me. Also .. why does it work with "response(get_settings());" That means that response function works properly, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the string in the parenthesis of `die()` and its equivalent `exit()`, the PHP manual states:

> If `status` (i.e. in your case the string) is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

and

> No value is returned.

So you can just use `echo` to get a visible output and after that, use `die()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. PHP manual also says:  `If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.`

Comment: I think your answer is correct but I'm confused by `die('<' . $str . '>');` Would that not then get treated as a string?

Answer (score 0):

i have done this check:

```
die('<' . $str . '>');   ----> doesn't work
die('#' . $str . '>');   ----> works !!!
die('#' . $str . '<');   ----> works !!!
die('>' . $str . '<');   ----> works !!!
```

So it doesn't like '<' at the begining.

Why ? And also, why has it happened this week?

NOTE: I could change these exterior characters, but I want to understand the real reason of the problem

Hi, anybody knows ???